# Can we write $||A - B|| \leq ||A||$?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I am confused with the very basic question related with the matrix norm.

Can we write  $||A - B|| \leq ||A||$ ?

Thanks for the help and time.

Comment: What if $B=-A$? What if $A=0$ and $B\ne A$? What if ...

Comment: You can write whatever you want, but as a statement about matrices and norms, it is not always true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot; let $A$ be the zero matrix. Then we get a contradiction.

Comment: Only if $B \neq \pm 0 $.

Comment: Of course, I meant in general we cannot.

Comment: Of course, I knew that you knew that.

Comment: @Miheer Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @copper.hat Assuming $A $ and $B$ non zero matrices and $B\neq A$ can we say that my statement is correct? Thank you.

Comment: Both Miheer and Andres have answered that already. No, it is not true in general. Take $A=I, B=-I$, for example.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you very much. :)

Comment: @mathscrazy: You are very welcome.

Comment: @copper.hat I thought it would be enough to assume $B \neq 0$, this would imply $B \neq -0$